# KeyAlias SignedApk Что это?

Tags: android

При создании SignedAPK уже подписанного ранее приложения нужно ввести этот ключ, где его можно посмотреть или в каком пункте я его уже раньше вводил ?

Comment: У вас только с алиасом загвоздка - а файл кейстора у вас на месте и пароли вы помните? В поле ввода алиаса есть значёк папочки - нажав на неё можно увидеть все алиасы в кейсторе.